# Selecting the Id of the item with a MAX value when doing a left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Each product in the database can have many revisions. Some products might not have any revisions at all.

ProductRevision table has the following fields: Id, Version, SubmitDate

I am trying to figure out how I can select a field called LatestRevisionId based on the MAX SubmitDate and if not revision then the field will be null

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Name, p.Price
FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductRevision pr ON p.Id = pr.ProductId
```

Do I have to do a sub select in my select? I really want to try and use HAVING but can't figure out how to do it with a left join.

**I was trying to do the following as a sub select:**

```
(SELECT Id 
 FROM ProductRevision 
 WHERE ProductId=p.Id 
 HAVING SubmitDate=MAX(SubmitDate)
) AS LatestVersionId
```

Please note that I am using SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: where is `LatestRevisionId` coming from?

Comment: @vkp LatestRevisionId is just what I want to name the custom field I am selecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using `row_number`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.Id, p.Name, p.Price, pr.id as LatestRevisionId, 
           row_number() over (partition by p.Id order by pr.SubmitDate desc) rn
    FROM Product p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductRevision pr PN p.Id = pr.ProductId
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

This will select a single `Product` with the latest matching row from the `ProductRevision` table.

---

If you just prefer to use `max`, then you need to `join` the table back to itself again:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Name, p.Price, pr.id as LatestRevisionId
FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductRevision pr PN p.Id = pr.ProductId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ProductId, MAX(SubmitDate) MaxSubmitDate
                 FROM ProductRevision 
                 GROUP BY ProductId) mpr ON pr.ProductId = mpr.ProductId AND
                                           pr.SubmitDate = mpr.MaxSubmitDate
```

This could perhaps return duplicates though if multiple revisions share the same date.

Comment: I am not sure if this is exactly what I need because I still need to list all products, but with the Id of the latest revision of that product.

Comment: @BlakeRivell -- Both of these queries will do just that -- list all products and only the matching relevant row with the latest submitdate from the revisions table.  The first should be faster though.

Comment: Awesome going to try it now! Sorry I misunderstood when you said single Product.

Comment: Using your second solution: I am getting duplicates of products in my listing. There are 3 of the same product showing if there are 3 records for that product in the ProductRevision tabel. Do I need to do a GROUP BY or something?

Comment: @BlakeRivell -- that second query could return duplicates if that share the same submit date...  Using `row_number` should work for your needs (and is supported in 2008+).

Comment: so your recommending that I use the first solution you gave or modify the second?

Comment: @BlakeRivell -- yes, you should try it.

Comment: Ok the first solution is good, but I also need to select things like the actual MAX(SubmitDate) and MAX(LatestVersion) would I use a separate LEFT OUTER JOIN on the same table?

Comment: @BlakeRivell -- no, just `select *` and you will get all the fields matching that latest record...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Name, p.Price, pr.RevisionId as LatestRevisionId
FROM Product p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT pr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY SubmitDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ProductRevision pr
     )
     ON p.Id = pr.ProductId AND seqnum = 1;
```

If you want to aggregation other values, then just do:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Name, p.Price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN pr.RevisionId END) as LatestRevisionId
FROM Product p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT pr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY SubmitDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ProductRevision pr
     )
     ON p.Id = pr.ProductId
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Name, p.Price;
```

This should be the simplest method to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I am already doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN on ProductRevision table to select things like MAX(CommitDate) and MAX(Version) because I need that info too, along with LatestRevisionId. Will I use your LEFT OUTER JOIN as a second outer join? Also I don't think this will work in SQLSERVER 2008. Sorry I forgot to specify that.

Comment: @BlakeRivell . . . Of course this will work with SQL Server 2008.  If you want to aggregate other columns, you can use conditional aggregation, instead of filtering in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **SQL Server 2012 and aboe**, below code will give you desired result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Id, p.Name, p.Price, FIRST_VALUE(pr.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Id ORDER BY pr.SubmitDate DESC) AS LatestVersionId
FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductRevision pr ON p.Id = pr.ProductId
```